# Tools that take a kinship matrix for phylogenetic decorrelation

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, phylogenetics, statistics, biostatistics

I have plant genotypes that have been classified as `Invasive`, `Wild` or `Domestic`. I am trying to investigate what explanatory variables (such as "leaf size", "width of petals" and other continuous variables) affect the probability of being classified a sone of the three groups. I therefore have to perform a multinomial logistic regression. However, I would like to account for phylogenetic non-independence using a kinship matrix.

**Are there R tools that can perform such regression?**

I considered [lmekin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxme/vignettes/lmekin.pdf) for example but I don't think it manages to take a response that can take 3 different categories. Is there some function I would be interested in (in the `ape` package for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you willing to do Bayesian model fitting, this is likely possible but will take some tinkering to make sure the models are what you think they are. [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) (via [rstan](http://mc-stan.org/interfaces/rstan.html) or [brms](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms)), can fit multinomial logistic regressions ([A demo from Thinkinator](https://thinkinator.com/2016/01/12/r-users-will-now-inevitably-become-bayesians/)).

If you can convert these models to pure stan code, then you can incorporate phylogenetic/kinship/arbitrary correlation structure into the model following [this example on github](https://gist.github.com/rmaia/5936586) ([or this one](https://gist.github.com/rmaia/5936508)). I have had better luck getting phylogenetic regression to work correctly in pure stan than via convenience functions.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gap/vignettes/h2.pdf) is also an explanation for similar analysis with MCMCglmm